# Suggest me a degree for Game development

Tags: game-design

Which degree I pursue to become a **game developer** and from where?

I have done BCA and now i want to become a **Professional Game developer** to work in companies like `ubisoft` or `ea games`.

Comment: No, you don't want to work for companies like those. Trust me. The larger the team the smaller your creative input.

Comment: You should get a degree in computer science. You'll be better off learning game dev by yourself than not learning crucial engineering stuff that they don't have time to show you in game dev programs.

Comment: @Philipp from my personal experience, there is no direct relationship between team size and creative input. That just sounds like an angry statement, not very helpful for the asker.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Game developing is not a government job. You don't need a degree to develop games, also you don't need that **Professional** title.

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions.